# iOS - UIButton system selected image

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton

I have a UIButton with a transparent image with a toggle for selected.
In the current configuration I am using the system button type, because it inverts the button nicely. However with this inverting, I get an image with borders, and I want this image to fill the whole button. How can this be achieved? I would like to keep the transparent mask from system.

[Here is the repository.](https://github.com/evenwerk/uibuttonsystemselectedimage)

In the image below is what the selected system state looks like.

[image]

Comment: What you want from image and button??

Comment: I want the rounded rectangle that iOS adds to invert the button on selected, to fill the whole button frame.

Comment: sry, its not clear to me.

Comment: The UIButton has 2 subviews, 1 for the button image, and the other one is the rounded rectangle. I want this rounded rectangle to fill the whole button frame.

Comment: You have to made custom.

Comment: @evenwerk Any success on this one?

Answer (score 0):

Create Subclass of UIButton and override the isSelected

For Example

```
  class CustomButton: UIButton {

    /*
    // Only override draw() if you perform custom drawing.
    // An empty implementation adversely affects performance during animation.
    override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
        // Drawing code
    }
    */




    override var isSelected: Bool {


        didSet {
            if isSelected {
                self.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue
                self.tintColor = UIColor.white
            } else {
                self.backgroundColor = .white
                self.tintColor = UIColor.red
            }

        }
    }

}
```

Change Color according to your requirements

And in view Controller Do Like this

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var button: CustomButton!
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    button.isSelected = false
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
@IBAction func btnTapped(_ sender: Any) {
    button.isSelected = !button.isSelected
}
```

}

And there is one more thing you have to set Render option of image to Template [image: Template Image]

Comment: For white backgrounds this works, but what about image backgrounds?

Comment: you have to make them white and apply the color on runtime